# How to make the object "looks" to the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making game with Unity2D. I have main character and Boss. Boss has gun, which should always be aimed on hero. How I can do this?

I tried this:

```
    public GameObject player; //main hero object

    void Update()
    {
        gameObject.transform.right = new Vector2(player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y);
    }
```

But gun behaves not as I would like (only works correctly when the hero is to the right of the boss)
And there is another problem - when i use `transform.up` or `transform.Rotate` or `transform.rotation` sprite not just rotating, but twisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is a built in function for that. See the docs here: [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

The following example code will only rotate your transform on the Z axis.

```
public GameObject Player; //main hero object

void Update()
{
    // you can lock axises by this technique
    Vector3 playerPosToLookAt = (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, Player.transform.position.z);
    transform.LookAt(playerPosToLookAt );
}
```

Comment: But it still bend terribly. Can i freeze x and y rotation?

Comment: Please extend your question with the current wrong behaviour and your expected result

Comment: Gun rotates, but not on the z axis only. It also rotates on x and y axes. Because of this, it looks like gun resizes all time. Can i freeze x axis and y axis rotation?

Comment: I see what you want